# Change date in jQuery Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, simpledateformat, countdowntimer

I have a simple Countdown Timer on my website.

I'd like to change the date from January 25th to October 24th at 9am GMT?

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEWJpY

I've done lot of Googling but very much confused about what needs to be changed.

```js
$(function () {
 var austDay = new Date();
 austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
 $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
 $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});
```

```css
#defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>jQuery Countdown Basics</h1>

<p><strong>25th January</strong> == austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);</p>

<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>

<hr>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>What is October 24th at 9am?</p>
```

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery countdown plugin?

Comment: @RaxWeber Not in the above excerpt but it is included in the Demo. Have you viewed the Demo? It should be counting down - it's just counting down to January 25th and not October 24th as I'd prefer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to use

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Will give counter until 24th Oct'16.

```
var austDay = new Date();
austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear(), 10-1, 24, 9, 0);
```

FYI,

- This is just an example, you can do necessary changes as per your need.
- Don't forget to add that `countdown plugin` in below example to get output.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function () {
 var austDay = new Date();
 austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear(), 10-1, 24, 9, 0);
 $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
 $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});
```

```css
#defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>jQuery Countdown Basics</h1>

<!--p><strong>25th January</strong> == austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);</p-->

<p>What is October 24th at 9am?</p>

<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>

<hr>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Loading.. - it was the formatting I was unclear on - thank you for clarification :-D